# unable to reach 100% code coverage in sonar for my gradle multiproject + java + groovy + clover + sonarqube

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, sonarqube, code-coverage

I created a simple scenario with sources, tests, and configuration. I am not able to my current setup reach 100% code coverage in Sonar even it should be. (link to repository with sources - https://bitbucket.org/sloukam/gradle-multiproject-coverage-sonar/src )

- It's a little bit complicated - it's Gradle multi-project which sources and tests mixed in java and groovy.
- Tests are in the same module as source class and sometimes test are in "general" test module (let's call it integration test module) and corresponding sources are located in their module (in this simple case in module source_module_one and source_module_two.
- Some sources are written in Java and covered by the Groovy test and vice versa.

After spending a lot of time I'm not able to see in my local Sonar 100% code coverage. I would really appreciate help to reach the target of 100% code coverage. Is it possible with my project structure? With any other coverage plugin?

Answer (score 2):

First, you should certainly reconsider having tests in the same directory as sources. Just for future sanity's sake, I'd segregate tests in a different directory. Additionally, if your tests are in with your sources, then they'll be counted *as* source files. So you'll need to have tests of your tests, and test of your test-tests, ... ad infinitum.

Beyond that, though, 100% coverage is a Grail Quest. Holding yourself to high standards is a good thing, but at a certain point you hit the law of diminishing returns. Instead, I'd set the requirement to ... 90%? 92%? 95%?

Comment: 100% coverage - I would like to say that all demo classes are covered by tests  therefore I expect 100% coverage is in this demo case right expectation. In real project it's like you wrote.

Comment: Why tests are not in same folder/module as source class? Because in this case test are really simple but in our real case one test (integration) is covering/testing more classes from different modules. This stupid demo case is just to see which classes seems as uncovered by test. Combination java-groovy (vise-versa) test in different module than source file... combination of these...

Comment: @sion see my expansion.

Answer (score 1):

- basically what we are solving here is typical unit tests / integration tests scenario. you have unit tests inside your modules but then you have another module / project that runs integration tests and you want to see combined coverage
- this can be really easily solved in SonarQube 6.2+ because it introduced new property `sonar.jacoco.reportPaths` - which takes multiple report files and merges them.
- in lower versions of SonarQube, you probably have to merge both unit and integration tests report files into one, using `JacocoMerge`. In our project, I added this task:

  task jacocoMerge(type: JacocoMerge) {
  subprojects { subproject ->
      executionData fileTree(subproject.buildDir).include("/jacoco/*.exec")
  }
  }

which generates report files that merges all reports over all modules into `projectRoot/build/jacoco/jacocoMerge.exec`. Now you can use absolute path to this file as `sonar.jacoco.reportPath` for all your modules you want to analyze.